# Add descriptive text to the right of field in Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a DecimalField in my model that I'd like to show up in the admin interface with a unit to the right of the field, like so:

[image: Desired UI]

I think if I add `help_text` to the field, that will show up below the field. Is there a way to specify it to show up to the right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle it with `help_text` from the `forms`, overwrite your field in the form, such as the `css`.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms
from your.models import Post


class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ethanol = forms.FloatField(
        label='This is Ethanol',
        max_value=10,
        min_value=0,
        widget=forms.NumberInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'whatever',
                'style': 'position:relative'
            }
        ),
        help_text='<span style="position:absolute;right:0">g/mL</span>'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'


class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PostForm
    list_display = ['ethanol', 'id']


admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```